# obtainStyledAttributes works wrong

Tags: java, android, typedarray

I am trying to create my own keyboard. Using Android Keyboard is not enough for my task so I decided to create inheritor class directly from View.class. As base I decided to use code of Keyboard.class and then start change things one by one.

I faced many problems trying even compile that class, used some reflection and hacks to obtain private fields. I created file attrs to be able to use Keyboard's attributes and tags.  Finally class compilled and know it crashes becouse parameteres, that should go from inflating, are null.

What I found out is that method context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyKeyboardView); returns wrong result and a.getIndexCount(); after that returns 0.

here is my attr.xml file:

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="MyKeyboardView">
    <attr name="keyBackground" format="reference" />
    <attr name="keyTextSize" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="labelTextSize" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="state_long_pressable" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="keyTextColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="keyPreviewLayout" format="reference" />
    <attr name="keyPreviewOffset" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="keyPreviewHeight" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="verticalCorrection" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="shadowColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="shadowRadius" format="float" />
    <attr name="backgroundDimAmount" format="float" />
    <attr name="popupLayout" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

here is part of my keyboard class:

```
public MyKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("keyboardViewStyle", "attr", "android"));
}

public MyKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
}

public MyKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.MyKeyboardView);

    LayoutInflater inflate =
            (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int previewLayout = 0;
    int keyTextSize = 0;

    int n = a.getIndexCount();
```

This is how I use keyboard in layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <com.test.features.keyboard.MyKeyboardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="2.5dip"
        android:keyPreviewHeight="@dimen/key_height"
        android:shadowRadius="0"
        android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/keyboard_key_preview"
        android:keyPreviewOffset="0dp"
        android:keyBackground="@drawable/keyboard_key_background"
        android:keyTextColor="@color/keyboard_key_color"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:popupLayout="@layout/keyboard_popup_layout"/>
```

tried to use it like so, length() returned 11, but switch case found almost no matches. And if found, default value was used:

```
int n = a.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int attr = a.getIndex(i);

        switch (attr) {
            case R.styleable.MyKeyboardView_keyBackground:
                mKeyBackground = a.getDrawable(attr);
                break;
            case R.styleable.MyKeyboardView_verticalCorrection:
                mVerticalCorrection = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(attr, 0);
                break;
            case R.styleable.MyKeyboardView_keyPreviewLayout:
                previewLayout = a.getResourceId(attr, 0);
                break;
            case R.styleable.MyKeyboardView_keyPreviewOffset:
                mPreviewOffset = a.getDimensionPixelOffset(attr, 0);
                break;
            case R.styleable.MyKeyboardView_keyPreviewHeight:
                mPreviewHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(attr, 80);
                break;
            case R.styleable.MyKeyboardView_keyTextSize:
                mKeyTextSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(attr, 18);
                break;
            case R.styleable.MyKeyboardView_keyTextColor:
                mKeyTextColor = a.getColor(attr, 0xFF000000);
                break;
            case R.styleable.MyKeyboardView_labelTextSize:
                mLabelTextSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(attr, 14);
                break;
            case R.styleable.MyKeyboardView_popupLayout:
                mPopupLayout = a.getResourceId(attr, 0);
                break;
            case R.styleable.MyKeyboardView_shadowColor:
                mShadowColor = a.getColor(attr, 0);
                break;
            case R.styleable.MyKeyboardView_shadowRadius:
                mShadowRadius = a.getFloat(attr, 0f);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you instantiating `MyKeyboardView`? Are you inflating a layout? If so, have you actually set any of those custom attributes on the `<MyKeyboardView>` in the layout you're inflating?

Comment: @MikeM. added code to question

Comment: Those attributes are going to be in your app's namespace, not the system namespace. Add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`, and change the `android` prefix on all of your attributes to `app`. (Lemme know if Android Studio complains about anything.)

Comment: @MikeM. thank you so much! Now I have many other problems but at least my keyboard was inflated and doesn't crash anymore. Create an answer, so I will check it as right one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom `View` attributes are going to be in your app's namespace, not the system namespace, so they weren't found in the given `AttributeSet` when they had the system namespace prefix on them.

Add the `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` namespace declaration either directly in the `<MyKeyboardView>` tag, or in an ancestor tag, and change the prefix on all of your attributes to `app`.

Note that the prefix can be any valid name you like, though `app` is probably the most common.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need your attributes being styleable You may not use "declare-styleable" at all. Just put your attributes in "com.test.features.keyboard.MyKeyboardView" tag without any namespace prefix and get their values like this:

```
attrs.getAttributeIntValue( null, "your_attribute", 0 );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).