# Android: attr values are not set for Keyboard and KeyboardView

Tags: android

I am using KeyboardView and Keyboard for my custom keyboard. Now Keyboard and KeyboardView is deprecated. So I followed the Google guides. I copied the source code of Keyboard, KeyboardView and attr values. But When I run the app I am getting error. I noticed attr value is not set for the keyboard and KeyboardView. How to resolve this. Please give some idea on this.

attr.xml:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="Theme"></declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="KeyboardView">
        <!-- Default KeyboardView style. -->
        <attr name="keyboardViewStyle" format="reference" />
        <!-- Image for the key. This image needs to be a StateListDrawable, with the following
             possible states: normal, pressed, checkable, checkable+pressed, checkable+checked,
             checkable+checked+pressed. -->
        <attr name="keyBackground" format="reference" />
        <!-- Size of the text for character keys. -->
        <attr name="keyTextSize" format="dimension" />
        <!-- Size of the text for custom keys with some text and no icon. -->
        <attr name="labelTextSize" format="dimension" />
        <!-- Color to use for the label in a key -->
        <attr name="keyTextColor" format="color" />
        <!-- Layout resource for key press feedback.-->
        <attr name="keyPreviewLayout" format="reference" />
        <!-- Vertical offset of the key press feedback from the key. -->
        <attr name="keyPreviewOffset" format="dimension" />
        <!-- Height of the key press feedback popup. -->
        <attr name="keyPreviewHeight" format="dimension" />
        <!-- Amount to offset the touch Y coordinate by, for bias correction. -->
        <attr name="verticalCorrection" format="dimension" />
        <!-- Layout resource for popup keyboards -->
        <attr name="popupLayout" format="reference" />
        <attr name="shadowColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="shadowRadius" format="float" />
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="KeyboardViewPreviewState">
        <!-- State for {@link android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView KeyboardView}
                key preview background -->
        <attr name="state_long_pressable" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="Keyboard">
        <!-- Default width of a key, in pixels or percentage of display width -->
        <attr name="keyWidth" format="dimension|fraction" />
        <!-- Default height of a key, in pixels or percentage of display width -->
        <attr name="keyHeight" format="dimension|fraction" />
        <!-- Default horizontal gap between keys -->
        <attr name="horizontalGap" format="dimension|fraction" />
        <!-- Default vertical gap between rows of keys -->
        <attr name="verticalGap" format="dimension|fraction" />
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="Keyboard_Row">
        <!-- Row edge flags-->
        <attr name="rowEdgeFlags">
            <!-- Row is anchored to the top of the keyboard -->
            <flag name="top" value="4" />
            <!-- Row is anchored to the bottom of the keyboard -->
            <flag name="bottom" value="8" />
        </attr>
        <!-- Mode of the keyboard. If the mode doesn't match the
             requested keyboard mode, the row will be skipped -->
        <attr name="keyboardMode" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="Keyboard_Key">
        <!-- The unicode value or comma-separated values that this key outputs -->
        <attr name="codes" format="integer|string" />
        <!-- The XML keyboard layout of any popup keyboard -->
        <attr name="popupKeyboard" format="reference" />
        <!-- The characters to display in the popup keyboard -->
        <attr name="popupCharacters" format="string" />
        <!-- Key edge flags -->
        <attr name="keyEdgeFlags">
            <!-- Key is anchored to the left of the keyboard -->
            <flag name="left" value="1" />
            <!-- Key is anchored to the right of the keyboard -->
            <flag name="right" value="2" />
        </attr>
        <!-- Whether this is a modifier key such as Alt or Shift -->
        <attr name="isModifier" format="boolean" />
        <!-- Whether this is a toggle key -->
        <attr name="isSticky" format="boolean" />
        <!-- Whether long-pressing on this key will make it repeat -->
        <attr name="isRepeatable" format="boolean" />
        <!-- The icon to show in the popup preview -->
        <attr name="iconPreview" format="reference" />
        <!-- The string of characters to output when this key is pressed -->
        <attr name="keyOutputText" format="string" />
        <!-- The label to display on the key -->
        <attr name="keyLabel" format="string" />
        <!-- The icon to display on the key instead of the label -->
        <attr name="keyIcon" format="reference" />
        <!-- Mode of the keyboard. If the mode doesn't match the
             requested keyboard mode, the key will be skipped -->
        <attr name="keyboardMode" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

I am getting error here:

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs, R.styleable.KeyboardView, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
int n = a.getIndexCount();
```

Here a.getIndexCount() return Zero.

And Here also I am getting error:

```
TypedValue codesValue = new TypedValue();
            a.getValue(R.styleable.Keyboard_Key_codes, codesValue);
            if (codesValue.type == TypedValue.TYPE_INT_DEC
                    || codesValue.type == TypedValue.TYPE_INT_HEX) {
                codes = new int[]{codesValue.data};
            } else if (codesValue.type == TypedValue.TYPE_STRING) {
                codes = parseCSV(codesValue.string.toString());
            }
```

codesValue.type should be 16 or 3. But I am getting 0.

If anyone modified Keyboard and KeyboardView please give me idea on this.

Comment: Are you still using the `android` namespace prefix in your XML? All of those attributes you copied are now in your app's namespace, not the system's. Also, are you sure they suggested to copy those attributes exactly like that? Are you sure they didn't suggest something like `<attr name="android:keyboardViewStyle" />`? Would you have a link to those guides?

Comment: I thought this seemed a little familiar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51543905.